# Exam question bothering me

Tags: phrase-requests

Are both options correct?

> How much time ______ with your cousin in London last summer?
>
> A. have you spent
>
> B. did you spend

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial attempts at research. I strongly encourage you to take the site tour and review the Help Center for additional guidance. Our sister site for English Language Learners may also be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Option B is correct. "Last summer" is entirely in the past, so you also refer to actions that took place then in the past tense.

Option A uses present perfect tense, which indicates an action that is ongoing or has continued until the present. You would use that tense if you were referring to a time period that includes right now (e.g. "this week" or "since last summer").